# How to keep one object alive as long as another object exists?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, ownership-semantics

Is there a way to prevent one particular object of being destroyed while another object still exists, *without* explicitly making the class of the second one to know about the first?

Here is an example:

```cpp
class A { /* A creates B*/ };
class B {};

int main() {
    auto spA = std::make_shared<A>();
    auto spB = spA->getB();

    spA.reset();
    spB->DoSomething(); 
}
```

After `spA.reset()`, I would like to have at least one reference to the object pointed by `spA`. Or, in other words: I would like to destroy the object pointed by `spA` only after calling `spB->DoSomething()`.

But, an important prerequisite is `B` is not allowed to "know" about `A` (e.g. it is not allowed to hold a pointer/reference to it).

As I understand, shared pointers provide some functionality which can help with dealing with this problem, but I am not sure which one.

**EDIT:**

The brief structure of `A` and `B` look as follows:

```cpp
class A 
{
public:
    A() 
    { 
        m_B = B::FactoryB(); 
    }
    std::shared_ptr<B> getB()
    {
        return m_B;
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<B> m_B; 
};

class B 
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr FactoryB()
    {
        return std::make_shared<B>();
    }
};
```

**EDIT2 (MY SOLUTION):**

So, using suggestion provided by @MSalters I was able to find a solution that works for me. In this case it was much simpler than expected, such that I only needed to adjust `A::getB()`:

```
    std::shared_ptr<B> getB()
    {
        std::shared<B> spBAlias(this->shared_from_this(), m_B.get());
        return spBAlias;
    }
```

Here, instead of just returning `m_B`, `A::getB()` creates and returns a shared pointer `spBAlias` of type `B` (using alias constructor), which influences the reference counting of the `A` object (provided by `this->shared_from_this()`). So, calling `spA.reset()` in the `main` decreases uses of `spA` from two to one, making the call of `spB->DoSomething()` possible. To use `shared_from_this()`, `A` needs to inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<A>`:

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I find your question slightly confusing. Why would you call `spA.reset()` if you still want the object to be alive?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to shoehorn manual lifetime management into a `shared_ptr`. This is pretty much guaranteed to not end well.

Comment: @AndyG, That's just a simulation of an "unwanted" access for example (e.g. another function/client tries to delete a component which is still used by the other).

Comment: There's no way to do this and comply with these strict requirements. C++ does not work this way. It's possible to make this happen, but only by slight changes to these requirements.

Comment: to me it looks like you want an explicit relation between the two without having an explicit relation between the two, but maybe I am just misunderstanding what you want to achieve

Comment: Ok, keeping my "requirements" aside, how would you approach this problem? The order of calls to `reset()` and `DoSomething` remains.

Comment: why does `B::DoSomething` need the `A` instance to be alive when it has no reference or pointer to it?

Comment: Maybe if you describe your concrete requirements we can help better. Right now it's hard to ignore the part of the brain that goes, "Why would you do this?" I also come up with my composition, normally, by imagining the objects as little people doing little things in a little office.

Comment: also it would help if you turned your code into a [mcve]. My brain goes on strike when you call `B::Dosomething` but `B` has no such method.

Comment: If `B` can't know about `A`, then the it feels like you need some life support object that forces `A` to stay alive until `B` has done what it needs to do.

Comment: `B` has member variables which hold references to some of the member variables from `A`. The initialization of those members happens during creating of `B` inside `A`'s constructor. This is why I need `A` object to be alive when I call `B::DoSomething()`.

So if for example `B` is in use by somebody (e.g. performing `DoSomething()`), and someone else is trying to "switch off / take away / deactivate" the `A` object, this should be prevented, since its resources are still occupied by `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shared_ptr` has something called an *aliasing constructor*. A `shared_ptr<B>` can be created from a `shared_ptr<A>` and a `B*`. The destructor of this `shared_ptr<B>` will delete the **`A`** object, not the `B`.

In your case, your `A` object could itself hold a `unique_ptr<B>`, or even an outright `B` member.

Answer (score 3):

You can absolutely do this using `shared_ptr`, but you'll have to write some extra code.

Just have `getB` return a `shared_ptr<B>` with a custom deleter ... the deleter should be a lambda capturing a `shared_ptr<A>` by value, and explicitly releasing *that* only when `spB` goes out of scope and tries to delete the `B` object.

`A` will have to derive from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) to get a viable shared pointer to itself from inside `A::getB()`.

If the `B` object is actually a subobject of `A`, then this is sufficient. Otherwise, you should really delete the `B` as well.

---

```
int main() {
    shared_ptr<A> spA = std::make_shared<A>();
    shared_ptr<B> spB = spA->getB();

    spA.reset();         // spB's deleter keeps the refcount nonzero
    spB->DoSomething();  // fine
}                        // spB's destructor finally deletes *spA
```

Comment: thank you! I like really your idea but I am not quite sure how to implement it. Especially the part with the lambda's capture providing `this->shared_from_this()` object confuses me, since I construct the `B` object within a factory function and not in `A::getB()`. I have editted the main question with the structure of `A` and `B`. Could you please elaborate in more detail how to define this custom deleter function in my case?

Comment: Ah, I see you've now described B's ownership model a bit, so this should be possible. Anyway, the gist is that `A` must use `shared_from_this` so that `A::getB()` can get a shared pointer to `this`. Then it can return a `shared_ptr<B>` with a deleter that captures that `shared_ptr<A>`.